# How to set an attribute into a session with thymeleaf?

Tags: spring, http, session, thymeleaf

I'm trying to add an attribute to an HTTP session with thyme leaf, but I can't. I had a "Project" object and I need to pass it to the controller. I had a form in the page, so I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
<input type="hidden" th:attr="${#session.setAttribute('proyecto', '${proyecto}')}"
```

The controller receives the attribute `proyecto` but the value is `"${proyecto}"`, not the content of the project object

Answer (score 0):

Send the value using a form and then set the session attribute in your controller.

**HTML**

```
<form th:action="@{/newProject}" th:object="${newProject}" method="post">
    <input th:field="*{id}"></input>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/newProject", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addProject(HttpSession session, @ModelAttribute("newProject") Project project) {
    session.setAttribute("proyecto", project);
    return "/newPage";
}
```

This is just example of course. You would need to add all the project fields in your `HTML`.